# how to find the swagger path

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have the following swagger config. now what would be my swagger path to open the swagger-ui in browser.

```
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex(".*/v2/accounts/.*"))
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
```

Comment: You should be able to get the swagger-ui path from the application start-up logs. Generally it ends with swagger-ui.html. In your case, path would be something like <context-path>/v2/accounts/swagger-ui.html e.g. http://localhost:8080/v2/accounts/swagger-ui.html

Comment: This is how swagger url generally looks like: http://localhost:8080/<APP_Context>/swagger-ui.html

Comment: yeah, that I know it should have path something localhost:8080/APP_CONTEXT/swagger-ui.html. But only issue is that I am not able to get the CONTEXT_PATH itself. 
localhost:8080/v2/accounts/swagger-ui.html -- this is not working @Akash

Comment: @GauravYadav What is your controller mappings? Do you have have any server.context-path set-up in your application.config too?

Comment: actually, I am new to this project and i don't see any server.context-path in application.cofig. And this project is using ANT build system so there is no application.config.And there is no controller mapping.

Comment: I am able to get the swagger-json response on this url **context-path/v2/api-docs** but when I am hitting the **context-path/swagger-ui.html** then it's throwing an error. please help here

Comment: What is the error that you are getting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below approach:

1. install globally on node package http-server using command - `npm install -g http-server`
2. Run `http-server --cors` after changing directories to where `your.json` is located
3. Open swagger ui (i.e. dist/index.html)
4. Put http://localhost:8080/your.json in input field and click "Explore"